# Google Calendar - trouble with setting Google_EventReminders

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to set a reminder in a calendar using the Google PHP libraries with this code:

```
        $rem = new Google_EventReminders();
        $rem->setUseDefault('false');
        $overrides = array("method"=> "popup","minutes" => "15");
        $rem->setOverrides($overrides);
        $event->setReminders($rem);
```

The event I am sending to the API contains the following data:

```
[reminders] => Google_EventReminders Object
    (
        [__overridesType:protected] => Google_EventReminder
        [__overridesDataType:protected] => array
        [overrides] => Array
            (
                [method] => popup
                [minutes] => 15
            )

        [useDefault] => false
    )
```

But the event itself does not appear in my calendar with a reminder.

Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong v.gratefully received. Thank you, Tony

Comment: ok ... solved the problem with: $overrides = array(array("method"=> "popup","minutes" => "15")); ... ie the overrides are a plural - themselves an array. hope my discovery process might be useful to others

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass an **array** of reminders in the *setReminders* method, as in this example:

```
<?php
  $reminder = new Google_EventReminders();
  $reminder->setUseDefault(false);
  $overrides = array("method"=> "popup","minutes" => "15");
  $reminder->setOverrides(array($overrides));
  $event->setReminders($reminder);
?>
```

In Google_EventReminders class, the method setOverrides only accepts an array of reminders to validate these settings (by the method *assertIsArray*), as shown below:

```
<?php 
 public function setOverrides(/* array(Google_EventReminder) */ $overrides) {
  $this->assertIsArray($overrides, 'Google_EventReminder', __METHOD__);
  $this->overrides = $overrides;
 }
?>
```